# Парсинг тела ответа http

Tags: python, http

Всем привет, у меня есть строка, которая содержит http ответ от одного сервера? Какие есть библиотеки для парса тела ответа? Можно ли как то это сделать через requests? Я пытался нагуглить, но в гугле только нашел как делать сразу запрос и его парсить например requests.get, но у меня ответ как строка.

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос строку-ответ и какую информацию вы хотите распарить из неё.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать такие библиотеки:

- [Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/)
- [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html)
- [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Также можно использовать библиотеку `requests` для парсинга тела ответа. Для этого необходимо использовать метод `response.text`, чтобы получить строку тела ответа. Пример кода:

```py
import requests

url = 'url'
response = requests.get(url)
body = response.text
```

Comment: Мне не нужно делать запрос на сервер! Я же написал. У меня есть файл, его нужно прочитать и распарсить http ответ. Если можно пример пожалуйста